# Helpme with postgres

Tags: postgresql

thanks for your answers and I have another question. I want to add at the end of a character extraction a hyphen and then a number that is autoincrementing in a column something

```
column1            column2
---------------------------
F001-0004-12344   12344-1
F001-0004-12344   12344-2
F001-0004-12344   12344-3
etc.
```

Comment: Concatenate with `row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ???)`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using external scripting:

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES('value') RETURNING some_value;
```

Then use what is returned by this query for an update statement. However, I would recommend creating a SERIAL column which will auto-increment for every insert.